# Get mime type of content scheme

Tags: android, mime-types, file-type

In order to send an image to a server from my android application, I have to get mime type of the image (or, at least, its extension).

I get the image from a `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` intent. Some applications, like Dropbox, send a `file://` scheme data, so I can guess the extension using `MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl()`, but some others, like Google Drive, send a `content://` scheme, which not permit to do so.

I've tried many things before posting here, like this:

```
AssetFileDescriptor asset = getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(getIntent().getData(), "r");
FileInputStream stream = asset.createInputStream();
String mime = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(stream); // returns null
```

The only workaround I think is to decode the asset into a Bitmap, then generate a new compressed image (using [`Bitmap.compress()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress%28android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream%29)), but it will add some work to the phone, and it could change the format/quality of original image, so I reserve it only if there is no other solution.

Does anyone have an idea about my problem? Thanks a lot for help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [@sh3psheep on Twitter](https://twitter.com/sh3psheep/status/354650822090571778), I've tried this, and it works for `content://` schemes:

```
Uri data = getIntent().getData();
String mime = getContentResolver().getType(data); // returns correct MIME type, such as "image/png"
```

The only con I found is that it does not support `file://` scheme, but we can handle it using method I described in question.